# Automapper conditional language mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a domain model that contains member variables for two languages, something like this:

```
public class Resource
{
   public string SwedishName;
   public string EnglishName;
}
```

For presentation I have a simplified model, that is delivered to a json serializer:

```
[JsonObject]
public class JsonResource
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public string Name;
}
```

These are mapped with automapper like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Resource, JsonResource>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SwedishName));
```

My question is, if this is possible to do in a more conditional way, depending on which language is asked for? My initial thought, was something along these lines:

```
string lang = "en";
json = Mapper.Map<Resource, JsonResource>(resource, lang)
```

Though, it does not seem possible to have several mappings for the same types?

Currently Im leaning towards, just defining another identical presentation model for the other language:

```
if (lang == "en")
    json = Mapper.Map<Resource, EnglishJsonResource>(resource)
else
    json = Mapper.Map<Resource, JsonResource>(resource)
```

Is this a feasible solution, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not create separate classes. Use `AfterMap`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Resource, JsonResource>()
 .AfterMap((r,b) => r.Name = isEnglish ? b.EnglishName : b.SwedishName);
```

`isEnglish` is the condition in your app, however you need to use it.

Comment: Or you can achive the same in .MapFrom() either like this:
.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => isEnglish ? src.EnglishName : src.SwedishName))

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different classes EngMapper and SimpleMapper which will implement the IMapper interface with a method initMapping for example after that you can create a factory in order to get the right mapper according to your language. So in the end your mapping will be separated for the different languages( that is better in my opinion ).